# Why do I get a stack overflow when I call the Windows API from my Delphi program?

Tags: delphi, winapi, drag-and-drop, delphi-10.4-sydney, getfiles

My form supports drag'n'drop of files from the Windows Explorer:

```
uses 
  ShellApi, System.IOUtils;

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DragAcceptFiles(Self.Handle, True);
end;

procedure TFormMain.WMDropFiles(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  hDrop: THandle;
  FileCount, NameLen, i: Integer;
  CurrFile: String;
  FileSysEntries: TArray<String>;
begin
  inherited;

  hDrop := Msg.wParam;
  try
    FileCount := DragQueryFile(hDrop, $FFFFFFFF, nil, 0);

    for i := 0 to FileCount - 1 do
    begin
      NameLen := DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, nil, 0) + 1; //+1 for NULL
      SetLength(CurrFile, NameLen);
      DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, PWideChar(CurrFile), NameLen);

      //If I don't do this...
      SetLength(CurrFile, StrLen(PWideChar(CurrFile)));

      if DirectoryExists(CurrFile) then
      begin
        //...I get a stack overflow here!
        FileSysEntries := TDirectory.GetFiles(CurrFile, '*.*', TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);
        //Rest removed for clarity...
      end;
    end;
  finally
    DragFinish(hDrop);
  end;
end;
```

Now if I don't strip the NULL (`#0`) character off the `CurrFile` string (see 2nd `SetLength`) I get a stack overflow when I call `TDirectory.GetFiles` and I'm now sure why.

Is the second `SetLength` (that strips `#0`) really necessary or should I do `NameLen - 1` for the first `SetLength`? Or maybe something else?

Comment: @KenWhite This is the stack overflow I was speaking about in another question (I remembered it back then as an access violation but it's a SO).

Comment: You should set the string length to whatever the function returns - it could still fail or copy far fewer characters. Why do you ignore the function's result with the second call?

Comment: @AmigoJack That's what I do... With +1 because the Unicode version doesn't include the NULL char in the count. This is a simplified example, I handle the fails in the real program.

Comment: On the **second** call you neglect the function's result. Why do you respect it with the first call and not with the second? Read my comment again - I've chosen those words with care, not sloppily.

Comment: @AmigoJack I get what you mean now (sorry English is not my main languages and sometime I read too fast and fail). Yeah if I do the second SetLength to the returned result of the second DragQueryFile that works too (and it's probably the solution)... I still don't understand how the #0 lead to SO.

Comment: SetLength takes the length excluding the null terminator so that +1 is wrong

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is not uncommon for people to include room for a `#0` character when sizing a `string` to use as a buffer for an external API to fill in, as long as they remember to strip it off afterwards.

Comment: @remy it may be common, but it's pointless. Get rid of the +1 and so get rid of the second SetLength and the StrLen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a few issues:

- you are calling `DragAcceptFiles()` only in the Form's `OnCreate` event.  If the Form's `HWND` is ever re-created during the Form's lifetime (it can happen!), you will lose the ability to receive `WM_DROPFILES` messages.

  You would need to call `DragAcceptFiles()` again with the updated `HWND`. You can override the Form's virtual `CreateWnd()` method to handle that.

  Alternatively, you can override the Form's virtual `CreateParams()` method to enable the `WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES` extended window style for each `HWND` that is created.
- your message handler is calling `inherited`. You *don't* need to do that.  The default handler will not do anything with the message.
- you are over-allocating memory for `CurrFile`.  You technically DO NOT need to include the null terminator when calling `SetLength()`, as it will automatically allocate extra space for one (a Delphi `string` is implicitly null-terminated, so that `PChar` casts can be used with C-style APIs that expect null-terminated character pointers).

  If you DO include the null terminator in the `string`'s length, you have to explicitly shrink the `string`s length afterwards, which you are doing (but not as efficiently as you could be, as `DragQueryFile(i)` will tell you the length to use without a null terminator, so you don't have to calculate it manually with `StrLen()`).  But, it is better to simply not over-allocate to begin with.

  Apparently having that extra `#0` in the string's length is causing problems for `TDirectory.GetFiles()` (or more likely, `TPath`, which `TDirectory` uses internally).  You should [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) about that.  But, you do need to make sure you don't leave the terminating `#0` in the string's length to begin with, since filesystem path APIs don't accept it anyway.

Try this instead:

```pascal
uses 
  ShellApi, System.IOUtils;

procedure TFormMain.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  DragAcceptFiles(Self.Handle, True);
end;

procedure TFormMain.WMDropFiles(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  hDrop: THandle;
  FileCount, NameLen, i: Integer;
  CurrFile: String;
  FileSysEntries: TArray<String>;
begin
  hDrop := Msg.wParam;
  try
    FileCount := DragQueryFile(hDrop, $FFFFFFFF, nil, 0);

    for i := 0 to FileCount - 1 do
    begin
      NameLen := DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, nil, 0);
      SetLength(CurrFile, NameLen);
      DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, PChar(CurrFile), NameLen + 1);

      if TDirectory.Exists(CurrFile) then
      begin
        FileSysEntries := TDirectory.GetFiles(CurrFile, '*.*', TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);
        //...
      end;
    end;
  finally
    DragFinish(hDrop);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: " If the Form's HWND is ever re-created during the Form's lifetime (it can happen!)..." Under which circumstances can the HWND be re-created?